# Firebase admin: User auth data validation

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to generate custom (JWT) token by using Firebase auth ***user email*** and ***password***

I understand that I can generate Custom token with *Firebase `uid`* but I want validate ***user email*** and ***password*** before generating Custom token.

`admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)`

How can I validate if user authentication is correct ? Code below only accepts ***user email***

`admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)`

The reason I am not using *Firebase native SDK* is, I am trying to access *Firebase db* from external project with already have *legacy Firebase* project.

i.e. I cannot use 2 firebase projects in one project.

Comment: What about checking `emailVerified` on the user object?  Whenever the Promise completes with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` or `signInWithEmailAndPassword` check the `emailVerified` and if not verified, resend with `user.sendEmailVerification`

Comment: You can try to use the node.js client SDK to signInWithEmailAndPassword to verify the email/password.